# Springdata JPA repository findAllByXXX() return null instead of an empty list

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using springboot 2.1.2 and I encounter some problems with repository.
Here are my entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    private User user;

    //other fields and getters and setters are ignored
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    private String email;

    //other fields and getters and setters are ignored
}
```

And my OrderRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

    @Query("select o from Order o where o.user.email = ?1")
    List<Order> findAllByUserId(String userId);

    List<Order> findAllByUser(User user);
}
```

When I invoke findAllByUserId or findAllByUser, the repository returns a **null value** instead of an **empty list**, this is so strange since I'm sure that my database has data.

I've read other similar questions, and they don't seem to help.

I try to fix the problem with debugger, and I track into the **AsyncExecutionInterceptor class**:

```
@Nullable
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    Class<?> targetClass = invocation.getThis() != null ? AopUtils.getTargetClass(invocation.getThis()) : null;
    Method specificMethod = ClassUtils.getMostSpecificMethod(invocation.getMethod(), targetClass);
    Method userDeclaredMethod = BridgeMethodResolver.findBridgedMethod(specificMethod);
    AsyncTaskExecutor executor = this.determineAsyncExecutor(userDeclaredMethod);
    if (executor == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No executor specified and no default executor set on AsyncExecutionInterceptor either");
    } else {
        Callable<Object> task = () -> {
            try {
                Object result = invocation.proceed();
                if (result instanceof Future) {
                    return ((Future)result).get();
                }
            } catch (ExecutionException var4) {
                this.handleError(var4.getCause(), userDeclaredMethod, invocation.getArguments());
            } catch (Throwable var5) {
                this.handleError(var5, userDeclaredMethod, invocation.getArguments());
            }

            return null;
        };
        return this.doSubmit(task, executor, invocation.getMethod().getReturnType());
    }
}
```

And I notice that in the 13rd line of this method, the variable result is the List with proper Order objects, but the if clause fails and thus return a null value.

So does anyone know how to solve the problem?

===========================================================

To make it more clear, I'll show my db schema:

[image: all tables names]
[image: orders table structure]
[image: user table structure]

and here are the sql generated by the Hibernate:

```
Hibernate: select order0_.id as id1_8_, order0_.address_id as address_6_8_, order0_.date as date2_8_, order0_.deliver_time as deliver_3_8_, order0_.restaurant_id as restaura7_8_, order0_.status as status4_8_, order0_.total as total5_8_, order0_.user_email as user_ema8_8_ from orders order0_ where order0_.user_email=?
Hibernate: select address0_.id as id1_1_0_, address0_.location as location2_1_0_, address0_.name as name3_1_0_, address0_.phone as phone4_1_0_, address0_.user_email as user_ema5_1_0_, user1_.email as email1_14_1_, user1_.password as password2_14_1_, user1_.pts as pts3_14_1_, user1_.status as status4_14_1_, user1_.user_name as user_nam5_14_1_ from address address0_ left outer join user user1_ on address0_.user_email=user1_.email where address0_.id=?
Hibernate: select restaurant0_.id as id1_9_0_, restaurant0_.email as email2_9_0_, restaurant0_.location as location3_9_0_, restaurant0_.name as name4_9_0_, restaurant0_.password as password5_9_0_, restaurant0_.phone as phone6_9_0_, restaurant0_.status as status7_9_0_, restaurant0_.type as type8_9_0_, restaurant0_.vcode as vcode9_9_0_ from restaurant restaurant0_ where restaurant0_.id=?
Hibernate: select address0_.id as id1_1_0_, address0_.location as location2_1_0_, address0_.name as name3_1_0_, address0_.phone as phone4_1_0_, address0_.user_email as user_ema5_1_0_, user1_.email as email1_14_1_, user1_.password as password2_14_1_, user1_.pts as pts3_14_1_, user1_.status as status4_14_1_, user1_.user_name as user_nam5_14_1_ from address address0_ left outer join user user1_ on address0_.user_email=user1_.email where address0_.id=?
```

Comment: I am not seeing any `userId` in your 'User' class

Comment: @AritraPaul I use `@Query` annotation and I specify the condition to User's email, so it doesn't matter whether userId exists or not

Comment: That's not the convention. try to follow convention and stick to it

Comment: @QYC, also I suggest you, to make standart repository queries, like `findAll()`, if it shows some result - good, if not - there are some problem in your codebase or configuration. so you need debugging.

Comment: @BSeitkazin wow, the findAll() also returns null...

Comment: @QYC, so I think I found a clue. I update my answer)

Comment: @QYC, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ambiguous. if you want to get order list by email then just write like below. There is no need of `@Query`

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

    List<Order> findAllByUserEmail(String email);

}
```

and entity class like below

I'm using springboot 2.1.2 and I encounter some problems with repository. Here are my entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    private User user;

    //other fields and getters and setters are ignored
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long userId;
    private String email;

    //other fields and getters and setters are ignored
}
```

Comment: It still returns null...I've changed the interface as you suggested: `List<Order> findAllByUserEmail(String email);`

Comment: You make `email` as `@Id` which makes it unique. That means there is no chance of getting a list I have updated my answer. Have a try

Comment: there is a **uni-directional** `many-to-one` relation between Order and User, what I want to do is to fetch Order which is owned by a specific User, and an user can map to many orders, therefore it should return a list instead of a single result.

Answer (score 0):

The following method signature in your `OrderRepository` interface should work:

```
List<Order> findByUser_UserEmail(String email);
```

Also, you can add the next one:

```
@Query("select o from Order o join User u where u.email = :email") List<Order> findAllByUserEmail(String email);
```

**UPDATE**

Try to query all entities, trying executing `findAll` from repository, if it is also `null`, you have some problem in codebase or configuration.

---

Try to update your class map definition:

```
public class Order {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_email")
    private User user;

}

public class User {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Order> orders;
}
```

Comment: @QYC, Are you sure, your table's name is `orders`? Which query generates Spring Data? What if you execute query in your DB engine? What is table structure in your DB? I really think that, you make some typo mistake.

Comment: I've updated my question, hope the additional information may help